# The request stream in highland is not correctly passed forward

Tags: node.js, stream, highland.js

I am having problems with getting work the nodejs `request` stream as I pass to map it's already empty array.

```
var _       = require('highland'),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

// This works but not using the stream approach
// function get(path) {

//     return _(function (push, next) {

//         request(path, function (error, response, body) {
//             // The response itself also contains the body
//             push(error, response);
//             push(null, _.nil);
//         });
//     });
// }

var google = _(request.get('http://www.google.com'));

google
// res is empty array
.map(function (res) {
    // console.log(res);
    return res;
})
// res is empty array
.toArray(function (res) {

    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request() module uses a sort-of old-style stream - it calls the .pipe() method on the stream prototype from the code Stream module:

```
stream.Stream.prototype.pipe.call(this, dest, opts)
```

https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/11224dd1f02e311afcc11df8a8f0be1d9fb2bf83/request.js#L1310

I traced the actual issue down to the following check in node's core stream module:

```
function ondata(chunk) {
  if (dest.writable) {
    if (false === dest.write(chunk) && source.pause) {
      source.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/stream.js#L50

This can be patched over by doing the following in your example above

```
var google = _(request.get('http://www.google.com'));
google.writable = true;
```

I raised a pull request to get this fixed properly at https://github.com/caolan/highland/pull/42, this has now been merged so the bug will no longer be reproducible as of version 1.14.0

Comment: I've now merged this pull request, so you might want to update highland and give it another shot :)